# Something like a trace inequality of $H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I have the following question:

Let $\Sigma$ an a surface inside of an open domain $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$, where $\Sigma$ divides $\Omega$ in 2 open domains (for example: $\Sigma$ could be a plane).

Let $g\in H^{1/2}(\Sigma)$. How can I probe that exists $u\in H^1(\Omega\setminus\Sigma)$ such that

$\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\leq C\|g\|_{H^{1/2}(\Sigma)}$?

where $C$ is a constant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify your definition of $H^{1/2}(\Sigma)$

Comment: Thanks for comment @wisher .
$H^{1/2}(\Sigma)$ is the space of restrictions to $\Sigma$ of the distributions belowings to $H^{1/2}({\cal M}_j)$, where $\Sigma$ is an open part of a smooth maifold ${\cal M}_j$. Recalling that $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ is the usual notation for the trace space on the boundary of an open set $\Omega$.

Comment: So I can understand in the way that $\|g\|_{H^{\frac{1}{2}}}(\Sigma)=\|g\|_{L^2(\Sigma)}$?